# Decrypting Saml assertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

Put simply, I don't understand how to decrypt Saml. I have scavenged around the internet and I cannot find any clear answer or tutorial of any kind that is remotely useful.

I have been using the ComponentSpace library to help decrypt but the documentation is....rather lame, and hardly provides the "How to".

Anyways, could somebody give me a quick rundown of the steps to decrypt a saml Assertion? If requested I can provide some code snippets...

(Been bashing my head on this for quite some time)

Comment: you got a sample token? It really depends on IdP and how they're configured- it can be sign + encrypt or encrypt+sign which would alter the steps..

Comment: Zaitsman is correct. Sometimes the entire assertion is encrypted, sometimes just elements are. In both instances, the assertion SHOULD not signed. In the first instance it's signed beforehand, in the second it's signed after the element is encrypted. If you're decrypting, you still only need the public key. In all cases, you will need to base64 decode the response.